# What is the best algorithm for static posture recognition with Kinect skeletal joints?

Tags: algorithm, kinect

Do you know any robust way of recognizing a static posture?

I have tried saving every joint position with a given interval Xmax, Xmin, Ymax, Ymin, Zmax, Zmin and then try to see if 20 joints are within the given intervals, but it does not work well at all.

After this I have tried with relative coordinates to the parent joint, but again... it does not work...

I don't know how to do this... Anyone who did this? I refer here only to static postures, not dynamic ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try by defining a distance between two postures.

First of all, you should **"normalize" every postures**, in order to have a relative position. You should chose a "base joint" (for instance, Spine or Head), and then subtract the base joint coordinates from all the joints coordinates.

Example:

[image: Skeletal joints]

In the above image, you can consider the joint number 2 as a base joint. So when you normalize all the joints, the base joint will have always relative coordinates equal to (0, 0, 0).

Then, you can **define a distance between two postures**. Let's assume that those postures are *Posture<sub>A</sub>* and *Posture<sub>B</sub>*. In one of my projects, I have used the following:

[image: Posture Distance]

In the above formula, *Posture<sub>A</sub>[Joint<sub>i</sub>]* indicate the i-th joint of the *Posture<sub>A</sub>*, which is made by *Number of joints* Joints. The *distance3D* refers to a classical [three-dimensional Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance#Three_dimensions).

Then, you should **define a constant threshold distance** (let's name it as *T<sub>D</sub>*).

Now you can say that two postures are "equal" (or, more precisely, similar enough to be considered equivalent) if:

**T<sub>D</sub> > PostureDistance**

I don't know if this is the best method, but in my case it worked quite well (and it is simple to implement).

Comment: i have tried what you have said...and i wanted to see the distance from 2 posture on the interface...it seems to show the distance between me and the kinect...in the posture distance formula you take the maximum distance between the same joints,but i get the distance between me and the kinect all the time. For learning a posture i do this: I parse every joint and substract x y z of HipCenter,for recognizing i load those postures,and i make an acquisition of a kinectskeleton every 400ms, i substract again the x y z HipCenter, and then calculate the distance for every joint

Comment: Add the code you use at http://pastebin.com/, and post a comment here with the link